# AngularJs evaluate ng-show quite slowly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, ng-show, angular-ng-if

**THE SITUATION:**

In my app i have a maximum number of section, 12.
But not all of them have to displayed every time, it depends if the object that contain the relative data is empty or not.

In the view i check each of these object, and if an object is empty i don't display the relative section.

That's it.

The problem is that this cause a significant delay in displaying the buttons (link to each section) in the main view. Between 0,5 to 1 second.
That's really too much.
Without ng-show the buttons are displayed immediately, but i need to make this check.

**THE QUESTION:**

There is something i can do to make AngularJs evaluating faster?

I have tried several way to make that check but the delay remains the same.

**ATTEMPT 1 - General function and ng-show:**

Using a general function that check if the object is empty:

```
$scope.isEmpty = function(obj) 
{
    // Return true if empty
    if (obj == null) return true;
    if (obj.length === 0)  return true;

    // Return false if not empty
    if (obj.length > 0)    return false;

    for (var key in obj) 
    {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The view:

```
<button class="button" ui-sref="app.section_1" ng-show="!isEmpty(section1_data)">Section 1 </button>
```

**ATTEMPT 2 - More simple check and ng-show:**

```
<button class="button" ui-sref="app.section_1" ng-show="section1_data.length > 0">Section 1 </button>
```

**ATTEMPT 3 - General function and ng-if**

```
<button class="button" ui-sref="app.section_1" ng-if="!isEmpty(section1_data)">Section 1 </button>
```

**ATTEMPT 4 - simple check and ng-if**

```
<button class="button" ui-sref="app.section_1" ng-if="section1_data.length > 0">Section 1 </button>
```

**CONCLUSION:**

The time that Angular need to evaluate, for all these 4 attempts, is the same.

I really need to speed up this process, but i run out of ideas.
Somebody knows how can i achieve it?

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide full example?

Answer (score 0):

Replace ng-show/ng-hide with ng-if

Comment: Why?  The only difference is ng-if has an isolated scope.

Comment: I have tried it already, as you can see in attempt 3 and attempt 4 :)

Comment: @R.Salisbury, not only, and also - `ng-if` not add element to DOM if condtion _false_, ng-show - always add, and just change style